# Is there any "vqmod" to allow multiple image uploading?

Tags: javascript, php, opencart, opencart2.x, vqmod

I Want a vqmod xml file to add ability to upload multiple images at once.
Is there such a things around?

Edit:
Opencart version:2.1.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i wrote a xml to add to "vqmod" on opencart 2.1.0.1
it works perfectly and not only allows me to upload multiple images at once, it add ability to select a directory as like as images

here the xml file on git:
https://github.com/mhd-jalilvand/oc-vqmod-filemanager-select_dir

Answer (score 0):

Check out the extension called ['Multiply Upload Image Files'](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=8221&filter_search=image%20upload&filter_license=0)

It seems like this is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks, but it was for opencart 1.5 but Im working on 2.0.1 version

Comment: Under the download it states that there are various different versions. There is also one called "multiupload_files2.0.0.0" which is compatible with "2.0.0.0, 2.0.1.0, 2.0.1.1, 2.0.2.0, 2.0.3.1, 2.1.0.1"

Comment: but its comersial version